# Touchstart Issue in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've used button element and on touch that button colour is change. I've used touchstart / touchend events with jQuery.

Now the issue is in chrome browser for touch device while making the long press touch the button disappears for some moment.

Code example:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $("#follow").live("touchstart", function() {
    $(this).addClass("active");
  }).live("touchend", function() {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Could you provide some code? It's difficult to understand the problem.

Comment: <script type='text/javascript'>
      $("#follow").live("touchstart", function() {
        $(this).addClass("active");
      }).live("touchend", function() {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
      });
  </script>